# How to get mutable string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am generating sql query and perfoming a lot of += operations on my string. It looks like:

```
insert_string = 'INSERT INTO ' + table_name + ' VALUES '
for row in data_frame.iterrows():
        raw_row = row[1].values
        insert_string += str(tuple(raw_row))
```

So if my insert_string are immutable every += operation creates new string. For example, in C# there is StringBuilder class for this, that could initialise empty string with given capacity. How can i do it in Python?

Comment: Note - you don't want to take this approach... it's subject to SQL injection attacks. Python libraries have a standard DBI API that allows you to safely build the query string - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807601/what-is-the-most-effective-way-of-inserting-python-dictionaries-lists-into-sql/11807972#11807972 for instance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps the most common way is to create a list of all the pieces, and join them with the `str.join` method, like this:

```
pieces = ['a', 'b', 'c']
text = ''.join(pieces)
assert text == 'abc'
```

Note that you call the `join` method on the **separator** that will come between the pieces. In the previous example, that was the empty string, but in your case you might actually want something like a space or even a newline:

```
pieces = ['a', 'b', 'c']
text = '\n'.join(pieces)
```

Additionally, you could get a file-like interface by using the [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/io.html#io.StringIO) class:

```
with io.StringIO() as query_str:
    query_str.write('INSERT INTO ')
    query_str.write(table_name)
    query_str.write(' VALUES ')
    for row in data_frame.iterrows():
        raw_row = row[1].values
        query_str.write(str(tuple(raw_row)))
    # Use query_str.getvalue(), as it will be deleted
    # when the 'with' scope is finished.
```

Answer (score 2):

what you are probably looking for is `StringIO`, which presents a file-like interface to a list of strings, and allows you to extract a single string at the end:

```
import StringIO

builder = StringIO.StringIO()
builder.write('INSERT INTO ')
builder.write(table_name)
builder.write(' VALUES ')
for row in data_frame.iterrows():
        raw_row = row[1].values
        builder.write(str(tuple(raw_row)))
insert_string = builder.getvalue()
```

Although, most python users are happy with using a list directly, as in [Rafael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28012510/65696).  For completeness here's your code translated to that style:

```
builder = ['INSERT INTO ', table_name, ' VALUES ']
for row in data_frame.iterrows():
        raw_row = row[1].values
        builder.append(str(tuple(raw_row)))
insert_string = ''.join(builder)
```

In the odd case that someone viewing this question actually needs a mutable string; I'm sorry to say that there's nothing quite like that, and the solution depends a bit on the exact problem you're trying to solve.  If you need a mutable *byte* string, that's available, builtin, as `bytearray`.

```
>>> b
bytearray(b'xaby')
>>> b[1:3] = b'yz'
>>> b
bytearray(b'xyzy')
>>> b.extend(b'foonly')
>>> b
bytearray(b'xyzyfoonly')
```

there's no equivalent action for `str`, though.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good article on [Efficient String Concatenation in Python](http://waymoot.org/home/python_string/) which very much fits your problem.

tl;dr: Use `join` with a list comprehension:

```
''.join([str(tuple(row[1].values)) for row in data_frame.iterrows()])
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, there is a module called `UserString` that contains `MutableString`.

```
from UserString import *

myString = MutableString('String')
myString.pop(0)
myString[1] = 'h'
print myString # prints 'thing'
```

Comment: That class was deprecated in 2.6, and doesn't exist in 3.x. There is a discussion about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651344/why-is-mutablestring-deprecated-in-python)

Comment: Really, I'm using it in 2.7.8.

Comment: Deprecation doesn't mean it was deleted, it means it should not be used in new code, and will probably be deleted in the future.